# sql query to find matches between two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table abc which has three columns a,b,c

```
a      b
apple    ram
ram      apple
```

apple can be eaten by ram but ram cant be eaten by apple
I want to write a query to fetch all the rows which has the above said relationship in order to delete all the rows with the relationship

```
a        b 
ram      apple
```

Comment: What happened to c? Did it get eaten by apple?

Comment: There must be some other table to know which is eatable and which is not. How can query know that?

Comment: if that table has column a as apple and column b as ram,then the table should not have column a as ram and column b as apple, we have to poll the same table to find this type of results, column c is not necessary in current context

Answer (score 0):

I think a join with itself could do the trick:

```
SELECT t.a, t.b
FROM "abc" as t left inner join on "abc" as t2 on (t.a = t2.b and t2.a = t.b)
```

Comment: this does not work, i got the following exception "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"abc" as t left inner join on "abc" as t2 on (t.a' at line 1
"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  
FROM tbl1   
NATURAL JOIN tbl1;
```

OR for one table

```
SELECT a.column_name, b.column_name...
FROM table1 a, table1 b
WHERE a.common_field = b.common_field;
```

Comment: the common filed value is not constant, is it dynamic while the query is being executed